Spring Multiple Security Filter Chains with XML config: which Expression-Based Access Control is used?
I have a Spring Boot application and I configure Spring Security with XML. I want to use OAuth2 resource server authentication on one endpoint (/a/b), and basic authentication on the rest. For actuator, I want no authentication.
My xml config looks like that:
    <security:http pattern="/a/b/**" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless">
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyAuthority ( 'SCOPE_profile')" />
        <security:oauth2-resource-server>
           <security:opaque-token introspection-uri="http://localhost:9009/realms/cac/protocol/openid-connect/token/introspect" client-id="ses" client-secret="QiaW7phxWDmQpYhuHfzU7JfVAmvKgMTY" />
        </security:oauth2-resource-server>
    </security:http>
        
    <security:http pattern="/**" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" create-session="stateless" use-authorization-manager="false">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/actuator/**"  access="permitAll" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/**"  access="authenticated" />
        <security:logout invalidate-session="true" delete-cookies="JSESSIONID,SPRING_SECURITY_REMEMBER_ME_COOKIE" />
        <security:custom-filter ref="basicAuthenticationFilter" position="BASIC_AUTH_FILTER" />
        <security:csrf disabled="true"/>
    </security:http>

    
    <bean id="basicAuthenticationFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter">
        <constructor-arg index="0" ref="authManager"/>
        <constructor-arg index="1" ref="authenticationEntryPoint"/>
    </bean>
    
    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="realmName" value="tmoes" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="md5encoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.MessageDigestPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg index="0" value="MD5"/>
    </bean>
    
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authManager">
        <security:authentication-provider>
            <security:password-encoder ref="md5encoder" />
            <security:user-service id="userDetailsService" properties="file:${ADAPTERS_CONF_DIR}/users.properties"/>
        </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>

</beans>

http://localhost:8080/actuator requires basic authentication despite <security:intercept-url pattern="/actuator/**"  access="permitAll" />. Furthermore, when authenticating with user/password, the request is not authorized and returns 403. Corresponding trace:
23:54:41.216-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/a/b/**'], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@6d13cd6d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4414ee28, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@486480e2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3c1f2651, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@5a004dd4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3a9a12a1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@67c020c8, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19740583, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1fbd0850]] (1/2)
23:54:41.216-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7244b40e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3647b274, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@23471f48, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@23bf19c9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@56f8ab05, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@31620971, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6b02909d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3726fc3b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1c8d9ac9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3d7d920b]] (2/2)
23:54:41.216-04:00 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Securing GET /actuator
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/10)
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (2/10)
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (3/10)
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/10)
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking LogoutFilter (5/10)
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout']
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/10)
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  Found username 'tmoes1' in Basic Authorization header
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
23:54:41.217-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
23:54:41.218-04:00 DEBUG o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    Authenticated user
23:54:41.218-04:00 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
23:54:41.218-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/10)
23:54:41.218-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/10)
23:54:41.218-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (9/10)
23:54:41.218-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (10/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter   Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]] before authorizing
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Authorizing filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
23:54:41.219-04:00 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Authorized filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
23:54:41.219-04:00 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Secured GET /actuator
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/a/b/**'], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@6d13cd6d, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@4414ee28, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@486480e2, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@3c1f2651, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@5a004dd4, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@3a9a12a1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@67c020c8, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@19740583, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@1fbd0850]] (1/2)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@7244b40e, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@3647b274, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@23471f48, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@23bf19c9, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@56f8ab05, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@31620971, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@6b02909d, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@3726fc3b, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@1c8d9ac9, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@3d7d920b]] (2/2)
23:54:41.219-04:00 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Securing GET /actuator
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (2/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (3/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking LogoutFilter (5/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter             Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout']
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/10)
23:54:41.219-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/10)
23:54:41.220-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (9/10)
23:54:41.220-04:00 TRACE o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (10/10)
23:54:41.220-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter   Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
23:54:41.220-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]] before authorizing
23:54:41.220-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Authorizing filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
23:54:41.223-04:00 DEBUG o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Authorized filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
23:54:41.223-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor     Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
23:54:41.223-04:00 DEBUG o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy         Secured GET /actuator
23:54:41.223-04:00 TRACE estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager  Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@4e950223]]]
23:54:41.224-04:00 TRACE estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager  Denying request since did not find matching RequestMatcher
23:54:41.224-04:00 TRACE o.s.s.w.a.ExceptionTranslationFilter      Sending UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]] to access denied handler since access is denied


I have the following questions:

why are the SecurityFilterChains executed twice? Note that I have disabled autoconfig for SecurityAutoConfiguration and ManagementWebSecurityAutoConfiguration.

why does /actuator needs authentication

why is it that when I replace <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyAuthority ( 'SCOPE_profile')" /> by <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyAuthority ( 'SCOPE_profile, 'ROLE_USER')" />, authorization is successful, and http://localhost:8080/actuator returns 200OK. It is as if the <security:intercept-url pattern="/**" access="hasAnyAuthority ( 'SCOPE_profile')" /> applies to the other security chain. Here's the trace in that case:


00:46:41.560-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/Entitlements/esintegration/v1.0/getEmergencyAddress/**'], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4824d077, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@7f5b0926, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5ea50a98, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4dc23273, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@39240aa3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58f259bd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4a59d584, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@52e2e426, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@ece769a]] (1/2)
00:46:41.561-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@b7952d2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@13515709, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3c5797c6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7e3b101b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2f4c83f1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@42c3b02e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@19598b38, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@80347b2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@943d0c2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@23471f48]] (2/2)
00:46:41.561-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Securing GET /actuator
00:46:41.561-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/10)
00:46:41.561-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (2/10)
00:46:41.561-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (3/10)
00:46:41.561-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/10)
00:46:41.562-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking LogoutFilter (5/10)
00:46:41.562-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout']
00:46:41.562-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/10)
00:46:41.562-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  Found username 'tmoes1' in Basic Authorization header
00:46:41.562-04:00  .s.s.w.c.SupplierDeferredSecurityContext Created SecurityContextImpl [Null authentication]
00:46:41.562-04:00  o.s.s.authentication.ProviderManager     Authenticating request with DaoAuthenticationProvider (1/1)
00:46:41.562-04:00  o.s.s.a.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider    Authenticated user
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter  Set SecurityContextHolder to UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/10)
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/10)
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (9/10)
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (10/10)
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]] before authorizing
00:46:41.563-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Authorizing filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
00:46:41.564-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Authorized filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
00:46:41.564-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
00:46:41.564-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Secured GET /actuator
00:46:41.564-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=Mvc [pattern='/Entitlements/esintegration/v1.0/getEmergencyAddress/**'], Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@4824d077, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@7f5b0926, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@5ea50a98, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4dc23273, org.springframework.security.oauth2.server.resource.web.authentication.BearerTokenAuthenticationFilter@39240aa3, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@58f259bd, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@4a59d584, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@52e2e426, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@ece769a]] (1/2)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@b7952d2, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@13515709, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@3c5797c6, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@7e3b101b, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@2f4c83f1, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@42c3b02e, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@19598b38, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@80347b2, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@943d0c2, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor@23471f48]] (2/2)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Securing GET /actuator
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (2/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (3/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking LogoutFilter (5/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.logout.LogoutFilter            Did not match request to Ant [pattern='/logout']
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking BasicAuthenticationFilter (6/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter (7/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking AnonymousAuthenticationFilter (8/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking ExceptionTranslationFilter (9/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Invoking FilterSecurityInterceptor (10/10)
00:46:41.565-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter  Did not set SecurityContextHolder since already authenticated UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]]
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]] before authorizing
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Authorizing filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Authorized filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        Secured GET /actuator
00:46:41.566-04:00  estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager Authorizing SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@42ce393e]]]
00:46:41.566-04:00  estMatcherDelegatingAuthorizationManager Checking authorization on SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ FirewalledRequest[ SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestWrapper[ org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter$HeaderWriterRequest@42ce393e]]] using WebExpressionAuthorizationManager[expression='org.springframework.expression.spel.standard.SpelExpression@3099ccfc']
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Did not re-authenticate UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken [Principal=org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User [Username=tmoes1, Password=[PROTECTED], Enabled=true, AccountNonExpired=true, CredentialsNonExpired=true, AccountNonLocked=true, Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]], Credentials=[PROTECTED], Authenticated=true, Details=WebAuthenticationDetails [RemoteIpAddress=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1, SessionId=null], Granted Authorities=[ROLE_USER]] before authorizing
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Authorizing filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Authorized filter invocation [GET /actuator] with attributes [permitAll]
00:46:41.566-04:00  o.s.s.w.a.i.FilterSecurityInterceptor    Did not switch RunAs authentication since RunAsManager returned null
00:46:41.567-04:00  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        GET "/actuator", parameters={}
00:46:41.567-04:00  s.b.a.e.w.s.WebMvcEndpointHandlerMapping Mapped to Actuator root web endpoint
00:46:41.568-04:00  m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor Using 'application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json;q=0.8', given [text/html, application/xhtml+xml, image/avif, image/webp, image/apng, application/xml;q=0.9, */*;q=0.8, application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.7] and supported [application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v3+json, application/vnd.spring-boot.actuator.v2+json, application/json]
00:46:41.569-04:00  m.m.a.RequestResponseBodyMethodProcessor Writing [{_links={self=[Link@46f1a5bf href = 'http://localhost:8080/actuator'], beans=[Link@3f33305 href = 'h (truncated)...]
00:46:41.570-04:00  o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]
00:46:41.571-04:00  o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        Completed 200 OK

